# Svn working copy to git working copy

Tags: git, svn

I recently converted our SVN repositories to GIT repositories.

Now we want to link our working copies to our git remote repositories.

Do we need to delete our working copies and git clone our repositories?
This would be inconvinient because we would lose uncommitted changes.

Comment: you might want to take a look at this: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-overview/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any uncommitted change at the svn working directory, you have two options:

1. copy changed files over to a git working directory and treat as normal git change.
2. create a new svn "wip" branch for every remaining change, commit changes from working directory there. Sync those changes into git. Checkout those wip branches at git working directories.